# how to use JFileChooser to open a file by just wiring the file name

Tags: java, jfilechooser

I can't open a file by just writing the file's name in the JFileChooser unless I'm in the same folder as it, what can I do to fix it?

```
    JDialog.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
                if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    FileFilter imageFilter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Image files", ImageIO.getReaderFileSuffixes());
                    chooser.setFileFilter(imageFilter);
                    File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                    String filePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
                    icon = new ImageIcon(filePath);
                    try{
                        original = ImageIO.read(file);
                        image = ImageIO.read(file);
                        width = image.getWidth();
                        height = image.getHeight();
                        if (width > 1000 && height > 1000){
                            image = null;
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Image is too big (maximum 1000px by 1000px)", "Message: ", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                        } else if (width > 1000 && height <= 1000) {
                            image = null;
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Width is too big (maximum 1000px)", "Message: ", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                        } else if (width <= 1000 && height > 1000) {
                            image = null;
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Height is too big (maximum 1000px)", "Message: ", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.out.println(e);
                    }

                    picture = new ImageIcon(image);
                    label.setIcon(picture);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just the filename will not work if you are not in the directory because the file will be searched for in the current directory in the opened `JFileChooser`. You will need to provide the `JFileChooser` with the complete absolute path to the file instead of just the file name

**NOTE:** i just simulate it in Notepad++ it just says the filename cannot be found, so you can check for the file existence before other operation, add this snippet to your code

```
JDialog.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        FileFilter imageFilter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Image files", ImageIO.getReaderFileSuffixes());
        chooser.setFileFilter(imageFilter);
        File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        if (!file.exists()) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The file "+file.getName()+"\ncannot be found !!!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
           showDialogAgain();
        } else {
          String filePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
          icon = new ImageIcon(filePath);
          ...
        }
    }
    ...
```

Read more on the [**JFileChooser**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html) documentation